# How do you get a Struts2 value from the .properties file programatically?

Tags: properties, struts2, actioncontext

Say I have a struts.properties file with a defined value uploads.directory .  How can I access that value from an Actioncontext programatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use getText("some.property.name") which return you the property value

http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html

Comment: @MandarPandit link has been updated to http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html

Answer (score 3):

Create `ActionSupport` Object and by using `getText()` method of `ActionSupport` class.

```
ActionSupport actionSupport = new ActionSupport();
actionSupport.getText("foo.bar");
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a resources folder under `src`.
In the `struts.xml` file add a constant e.g., `<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global"></constant>`
Here global is the name of properties file.
Now you will be able to use the properties in the entire application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
    <!-- constant to define result path locations to project root directory -->

    <!-- constant to define global resource bundle -->
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global"></constant>

    <package name="user" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="home">
            <result>/home.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="welcome" class="com.waqar.struts2.actions.WelcomeAction">
            <result name="success">/welcome.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

The welcome.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title><s:property value="getText('action.welcome.title')"/></title>
    </head>
    <body>
             <s:property value="getText('action.welcome.username')"/>: <s:property value="username"/><br>
    </body>
    </html>
```

global.properties

```
action.welcome.username=waqar
```

In action class

```
System.out.println(getText("action.welcome.username"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the my.properties file or my_locale.propeties file in the package that houses your action class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the values in properties files other than struts.properties for examples `ApplicationResources.properties` or `my.properties` which needs to be in the classpath. struts.properties file is used to load struts specific properties for example `struts.i18n.encoding=UTF-8` or `struts.devMode = false` etc.

The thing you need to do in struts.properties after you create the properties file for your customized messages is you have to add the following property in struts.properties file

```
struts.custom.i18n.resources=ApplicationResources
```

If you have more than one custom message property files then you need to add them by separating with comma for example:

```
struts.custom.i18n.resources=ApplicationResources,my
```

Then in your action classes you can access the property values by using `getText('propertyName')`

Answer (score 0):

you can get value from message resource file like this:

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {

   public String getUserDetails() {
      if("First Name".equals(getText("label.firstName"))) {
          System.out.println("In if block");
      }
   }
}
```

you can also get more information, how to get values from `.properties` files in java class or jsp files.
for JSP:

```
<s:text name="label.firstName" />
```

and

```
<s:property value="getText('label.age')" />
```

for more information you can go through this link:
[get info here](http://www.jkstack.com/2013/08/how-to-use-resource-bundle-to-retrieve-the-message-from-properties-file-in-struts-2.html)