# JSP's displaying property name instead of value after form submission in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, internationalization

I have a JSP that contains lots of `s:text`'s and `s:property`'s. There are also some `s:iterator`'s with `s:text`'s inside them. The issue I'm facing is that once I submit the form and try to show something on the same JSP, all the `s:text`'s and `s:property`'s which used to display the values corresponding to properties started displaying just the property names.

Like

```
login.username=Username
```

JSP:

```
<s:text name="login.username" />
```

On submitting the form and returning to the same JSP, the property name: `login.username` shows up on the page where it used to display `Username`. Any idea why?

Comment: post your Action and your struts.xml too, and make a try using getText(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711093/how-do-you-get-a-struts2-value-from-the-properties-file-programatically

Comment: getText() usage worked fine for me. But on the initial page load, simple <s:text name="login.username" /> sufficed which is not the case after the loading of the same page on form submission. Why is that the case?

Comment: There's not enough information here to help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely no [`i18n`](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/i18n-interceptor.html) interceptor on the action stack or you don't have resource bundles for the used locale or default locale used by the JVM.

> Essentially, the i18n Interceptor pushes a locale into the
>   ActionContext map upon every request. The framework components that
>   support localization all utilize the ActionContext locale.

---

Comment: Alright, I think this could be the reason- my action has an interceptor associated with it. login.jsp form Submit -> Interceptor -> LoginAction.java -> login,jsp and there you go all the resource property references are empty! Of course it all just worked when I made use of the global resource bundle but I'd prefer to know if there was a way to access package.properties like before and still access all the properties in this case.

Comment: It's an option #5 from the [localization guide](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/localization.html)

Comment: Does that mean I have to relocate my package.properties? I previously had it under ~/com/example/login. My action is under ~/com/example/login/action and my interceptor's under ~/com/example/login/interceptor. Do you mean I need to place the package.properties in the same folder as global.properties (parent of com folder) and get rid of global.properties?

Comment: it doesn't matter it will traverse the package hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

If you use one properties file per action to store your i18n messages then you can have following situation:

```
ActionA.java -> 1.jsp
ActionB.java -> 1.jsp
ActionA.properties (all i18n messages are defined only here)
```

On ActionA everything is OK, but after submit on ActionB stuts cannot find corresponding i18n messages.

Comment: This isn't my case so I tried the getText thingy which worked for me.